# The [string-array] tag is being misused

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag wiki for [string-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-array) says a string array is "An array of strings that can be referenced from the resource class (R) in an Android application."

Most of the questions there don't even have anything to do with Android. They are just questions about arrays of strings. Should the tag wiki be changed or the tag renamed/burninated? (Tell me if I'm wrong, but it seems like a pretty useless tag).

Comment: Sounds the same as "string-table" in Win32.  Definitely more to it than just an array of strings, for example, resources need to be localized to the user's language.

Comment: Now it is a synonym for [tag:arrays] ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really necessary, then I propose to rename the tag to [android-string-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-string-array), and clean-up the questions that have nothing to do with it.

In my opinion, outside of Android context, if [string-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-array) is defined as "an array of strings" only, then I feel it is a meta tag. However, there are [bytearray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bytearray), [char-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/char-array), [bitarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitarray), [character-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-arrays), but no [integer-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integer-array).